# reverse() function in Django class based views with argument

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a URL like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/profile/$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

When the user clicks on `Update Profile` I do the update of form and redirect to the same Profile URL with `message` using `messaging framework`.

```
# views

# Use the message framework to pass the message profile successfully updated
messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')

# Redirect to the same view with the profile updated successfully message
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=(request.user.id,)))
```

But I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /5/profile/

Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(5L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting that because of how Python 2.x.x works.

All integers that comes from a database row will get suffixed with `L` or `l` (t commonly the capital `L`).

One way that'll work quick and dirty is

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=(int(long(request.user.id)),)))
```